# Facebook - what is the current access token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

After logging in with `{scope:'publish_actions,manage_pages'}`, I request the list of pages using the graph API as

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response)  {

  .....
  ..... this gives me the list of pages and their page tokens

 }
```

Now my Question is which access token or page token would future "/me" be translated to?

For example, I now refer to

1) `FB.api("/me",............)` Does this me refer to the user id or any of the page id's retrieved above?

2) `FB.api("/platform",........)`  Again which page will the api read here? (I am confused because I don't see the page-id being passed explicitly to the api function.

Answer (score 0):

> FB.api( "/me",... .........) Does this me refer to the user id or any of the page id's retrieved above?

That depends of course on the access token used to make the request – if it’s a user access token, it will refer to the user, and if it’s a page access token, it will refer to the page. (And if it’s just the app access token, then it will result in an error.)

> FB.api( "/platform", ........) Again which page will the api read here ?

The one that has the username `platform` set of course.

> ( I am confused because I don't see the page-id being passed explicitly to the api function.

It does not *have* to be an id, usernames of users or pages work as well. (Well, expect for the fact that the field `username` has been removed in API v2.0.)